# ORACLE: group distinct columns of a row excluding zeros

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table (see sample table data below) in which corresponding to a single identifier, I have multiple records. My requirements is to group the distinct non-zero data in every column as comma separated value and then corresponding to each identifier, get a single record having this combined data in separate columns instead of rows.

[image]

[image: Desired Output]

Comment: listagg something?

Comment: OK, so what have you tried?

Comment: listagg I think will combine rows together not data in columns. That too I dont need to combine all but selective

Comment: I dont understand your expected output. Can you explain how you expect any one of the values?

Comment: I am not sure of how to merge the data in columns to form the col_summary data. To get the records in same row from multiple rows, I could use self join.

Comment: Please post data as formatted text, [not  screenshots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557).Also, what have you tried so far and why isn't it working?

Comment: Ok will share the data as formatted text and will update it soon. Thanks

Comment: Also, please try to better explain the logic and/or check whether the example is correct. For example, in columns `colX1` for `key1` I see the values `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`. Why is the expected result different?

Comment: col1_summary is the ordered group of distinct values of all the columns for record with key1 as the identifier and 1 as the rcd_nbr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should work, even if not the prettiest. First collapses value columns to a single column with union, then use listagg to summarize.

```
with a as (
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,cola1 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,cola2 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,cola3 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,colb1 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,colb2 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,colb3 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,colc1 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,colc2 as value
from table
UNION ALL
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,colc3 as value
from table
)

,b as (
select identifier, rcd_nbr, case when value = 0 then null else value end as value
from a
)

,c as (
select identifier
      ,rcd_nbr
      ,LISTAGG(value, ',') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY value) OVER (rcd_nbr) AS concat
from b
)

,d as (
select identifier
      ,case when rcd_nbr = 1 then concat else null end as col1_summary
      ,case when rcd_nbr = 2 then concat else null end as col2_summary
      ,case when rcd_nbr = 3 then concat else null end as col3_summary
from c
)

select identifier
      ,max(col1_summary) as col1_summary
      ,max(col2_summary) as col2_summary
      ,max(col3_summary) as col3_summary
from d
group by identifier
```